# how to install android studio in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to ubuntu, donno how to use it, i want to install android studio in ubuntu, but is not easy as for windows, i have downloaded tools_r25.2.3-linux.zip file and android-studio-ide-145.3537739-linux.zip file, not able to install them. Please tell me the step by step procedure to install android studio and required jdk. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install `android-studio` open the terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer oracle-java7-set-default
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

Also you can install `android-studio` following this [tuto](http://www.upubuntu.com/2016/09/how-to-install-android-studio-under.html):

```
git clone https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make 
cd ubuntu-make 
bin/umake android
```

Comment: Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=350m'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.